# Inheritence in Symfony3 with discriminator

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine, discriminator, symfony3.x

I want to create this tables description in symfony:

GeneralAssignment:

- id (int)
- name (text)
- course (Course)
- type (1|2)
- assignment (Assignment1 if type==1|Assignment2 if type==2)

Course:

- id (int)
- name (text)

Assignment1:

- id (int)
- general_assignment (GeneralAssignment)

Assignment2:

- id (int)
- general_assignment (GeneralAssignment)

So the best solution is to use this relation schema:

[Simple relation ManyToOne] (Course) : Course.id <------> GeneralAssignment.course (GeneralAssignment)

And

[JOINED Ineritence type] (GeneralAssignment) : GeneralAssignment.type [1=Assignment1|2=Assignment2]

So I will get this class model (sorry for this bad photo):

[image: class model]

**Problem**

I used to create this model because I want to firstly, create the Course, then create the GeneralAssignment using the course id and finally, create the specific assignment using the general assignment's id

The problem is, I can't create a relation doctrine relation between Assignment1 and GeneralAssignment using Assignment1.general_assignment : "Cannot instantiate abstract class AssignmentGeneral". (the same thing between Assignment2 and AssignmentGeneral).

I need the Assignment1.assignment_general attribute because i'm going to use Assignment1 and Assignment2 classes later and if I can't know the general_assignment id, I can't even know the assignment general informations because of the inheritence from AssignmentGeneral to the specific Assignment classes (Assignment1, Assignment2)

The AssignmentGeneral is an abstract class because of the DiscriminatorMap requires that the class should be abstract.

So what to should I do ?

I can't set the AssignmentGeneral from "abstract class" to "class" and I can't create a relation between Assignment1 (or Assignment2) and GeneralAssignment in Assignment1

PS : These class names are not the real ones, but they are similiar to my real problem. Just to get it simple, I exposed this simple problem.

Thank you very much for each answer

Best regards

[Edit]
I'm adding the AssignmentGeneral declaration

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="assignment_general")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="integer")
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
       1 = "Assignment1",
 *     2 = "Assignment2"
 * })
 */
abstract class StatisticsGeneralAbstract
{
 //...
}
```

And also:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="assignment1")
 * 
 */
class Assignment1 extends AssignmentGeneral
{
//...
}

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="assignment2")
 * 
 */
class Assignment2 extends AssignmentGeneral
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Because If I remove the "abstract", I got this error "'AssignmentGeneral' has to be part of the discriminator map of 'AssignmentGeneral'". And I only need the Assignment1 and the Assignment2 classes in the DiscriminatorMap() and not the AssignmentGeneral class. In the end, I need to use the class that give me informations about the AssignmentX and AssignmentGeneral classes.

Comment: [Sorry I deleted my comment by mistake] Yes, that's because all the classes have to be in the discriminator map, that's how single table inheritance works.

Comment: No problem, I used the Joined inheritance. But what you said works also for Joined inheritance. I added the AssignmentGeneral declaration.

Comment: Ok. What's the reason for making AssignmentGeneral a mapped superclass?

Comment: Do you still need help? If not, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes that's why the AssignmentGeneral is a mapped superclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Class table inheritance ('JOINED')](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) doesn't require the parent class to be abstract.

Besides, one of the benefits of inheritance is to get the parent's properties when you instantiate a child class. So you don't have to instantiate both, just instantiate `Assignment1` or `Assignment2`.

Add relations to both of them in the Course entity and an `assignmentType` property so that you know which one it's linked to.

Comment: Sorry for answering late. I figured out that I need to read again the documentation of inheritance. And after reading your answer, I tried many solutions but I don't get the answer that I need. Maybe your answer helped me to correct the code, that's why i marked your answer as a solution. I found that The child and the parent class have the same id. So I don't need an extra attribute to get the parent class from the child class. That's disappointing because I want to create a relation ManyToOne (many Assignment and One AssignmentGeneral). But I can't did that.

Comment: But, can you please recommand me what should I do to create such relation even by ignoring the inheritance ?

Comment: By the way, If there is a solution using the ingeritance, I shouldn't have the Assignment data (childs) and the AssignmentGeneral (parent) data in the same table, that's why in the begining I choosed the JOINED inheritance type. But, I when I'm going to persist the AssignmentGeneral object, it persist automatically the Assignment object using the same id. And even if I can trick it by persisting a new Assignment object, without persisting the AssignmentGeneral object, I can't link the persisted Assignment object to the non persisted AssignmentGeneral object